# How to extract a word that appears at a particular place in the sentence?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I want to be able to extract first and last name out of this sentence. All of them have a pattern of `contact:`  `first_name` `last_name`

Here is an example of how the sentence looks:

> Contact: Girts Skenders 29178408 ext +371 girts.skenders@lu.lv

I want to extract `Girst Skenders`

I used this formula to extract the email out of the sentence:

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("@",A2)-1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))&MID(A2,FIND("@",A2),FIND(" ",A2&" ",FIND("@",A2))-FIND("@",A2))`

Comment: If the email is always last does this https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-word work for extracting the email?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Be sure to check out the *[tour]* (you'll earn your first badge!).  Which of your examples is correct - the one in your question's title with all the quotes, or the one in your question?  - Also it's best for the title to contain only the general subject of your question.  Data, code and examples should be in the body of the question. See "[ask]" as well as this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and "How to create a [mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),3*999-998,999))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant and not so obvious solution!

Answer (score 1):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"Contact: (\w+ \w+)")
```

- `\w+`  one or more letters

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query as its the most self explanatory - by selecting number of columns you easy choose which word or words you would like to extract.

[image]

Code:

```
=QUERY(SPLIT(C2," ",0,0),"select Col2, Col3",0)
```